# A registration error occurs when I try to register a new Stack Exchange account while being on the page of a migrated question

Tags: bug, error-message, sign-up

I posted [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/220950/would-a-solar-flare-that-wipes-out-all-of-the-worlds-financial-data-cause-hyperi) on Economics Stack Exchange. The moderators there didn't think it belonged there and migrated the question to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange instead.

I didn't have a Worldbuilding Stack Exchange account yet when that happened so I tried creating one while the migrated question was loaded in my browser. I was unable to register a new account (while still being logged in with my Economics SE account), I got a message stating that an unknown error had occurred and that I should contact an admin if this problem keeps occurring in the future.

I tried repeatedly to create an account in the following two days after the migration but to no avail. Today I found out what caused the bug. When you go to the migrated question directly by entering the address in the browser or when you navigate to it via the 'question migrated' message in the inbox of any of your SE accounts the same error will occur.

If however I go to the profile page of my Economics account and navigate to the migrated question via the link in the `questions` window of my profile the bug will not occur. I managed to create an account after finding this out. But I still wanted to report this bug here on the meta SE because it is a bit of a confusing bug.

EDIT: Here's my [Economics account](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/38837/maurice)

EDIT 2: I also found a smaller bug while looking at the title of this question from my Economics account profile page. Someone has corrected a spelling error in the title (whipe is not wipe) but this change does not propagate to the title of the same question that's displayed on the profile page of my Economics account. The word wipe is still displayed as whipe there.

Comment: Your identification of the bug doesn't make sense. Both would take you to exactly the same place... How you got to the question would make no difference at all when trying to register. Did you by chance use a different device or IP? I can see an IP that you've used recently is currently blocked for spam, which would have prevented you from creating a new account if you were accessing from that IP.

Comment: @animuson i'm using `NordVPN` when i browse the web. I also found a different error, please see my edit.

Comment: It's certainly possible that you'll encounter blocked IPs when using a public VPN then. I'd guess you were just being blocked and it had nothing to do with the migration. Your edit is by-design. Changes made on Worldbuilding will not be transferred to Economics.

Comment: @animuson a blocked IP was probably the cause of it. Because now that you mention it i do remember changing my VPN server location from germany to the netherlands at about the same time when i retried creating a world building account.

Comment: @animuson Would i be allowed to add a suggestion to this question and also add the `feature-request` tag to it? Because I would like to suggest that the error message that appears be changed into something more informative whenever someone tries to create an account using a blocked ip address. Right now there was no way for me to know that i couldn't create a new account because of the ip address i was using. More and more people are using VPNs now-a-days  so this problem could reoccur in the future. A custom error message could avoid a lot of unnecessary support requests.

Comment: Or should i make a separate question for a feature request

Comment: Some error messages directed toward potential spammers are intentionally kept nondescript to prevent spammers from catching on to the real reason why their actions are being blocked.

Comment: As Sonic mentions, I believe this error is intentionally vague. It's unlikely we would change it.